# How to scroll to an element that does not appear in the view using python and appium

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium, appium-android, python-appium

I try to scroll to an element by text that does not appear in the display with the following functions

```
self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)" + ".instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text('מטבע חוץ').instance(0))")

self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).getChildByText(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView"), "' + text + '")')
```

The functions do not scroll the element

This is my desired capabilities

```
desired_cap = {
    "deviceName": deviceName,
    "udid":uid,
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": platformVersion,
    "automationName":"UiAutomator2",
    "appPackage": "com.******.********",
    "appActivity": "com.*****.ui.*********"
}
```

I know there is a touch action method but it works only with visible elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each in range(1, 2):
      driver.swipe(500, 1700, 500, 1000, 400)
```

This does scroll screen 2 times if you need to scroll more than that change range values. for eg, 10 times scroll would be like range(1, 10)